# How to create tables separately using PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have these simple sql statements

```
CREATE TABLE a AS (SELECT 1); -- query #1
CREATE TABLE b AS (SELECT 2); -- query #2
```

The two tables are created only when the two queries are both finished.

If query #2 runs into any error (or takes much longer than the query #1), neither table `a` nor `b` will be created (or table `a` will not be present until query #2 finishes).

I hope there is a way to create tables one by one, that is, after table `a` is created, then query #2 is allowed to run, table `a` thus will be saved (or present) even query #2 runs into errors (or takes much longer time to run).

I googled it with several keywords but in vain. Any solution?

Comment: 1) dont use loops 2) show us the structure of your table(s) 3) show us your function 4) show us your (intended) result 5) dont use loops

Comment: @wildplasser thanks. I am seeking a general solution. Could you tell me if PSQL could run a part and output results and run another and output corresponding results?

Comment: The general solution is 1) dont use loops 2) show us your code

Comment: write results where?.. to stdoutput? to a table?

Comment: @VaoTsun suppose I have a simple sql file like `CREATE TABLE a AS (SELECT 1); CREATE TABLE b AS (SELECT 2); ` The two tables are created only when the two queries are both finished, if query #2 runs into errors (or takes much longer than the query #1), neither table `a` nor `b` will return (or table `a` will not be present until query #2 finishes). I hope there is a way to create tables separately, that is, after table `a` is created, then query #2 is allowed to run, table `a` thus will be saved (or present) even query #2 runs into errors (or takes much longer time to run). Any solution?

Comment: Please edit your question with code samples. I'm afraid I don't understand what you want from the text. Also please try to make your question clear and single, don't put technical task documentation into a comment

Comment: @VaoTsun Thanks for your suggestion, I just tried my best to edit my question, hope that will be simple and clear.

Comment: I assumed you are talking about transaction. check out my answer - is it what you wanted?

Comment: Simply run both statements with autocommit turned on.

Comment: Table `a` will be created before the second query starts but it will only be visible after the transaction finishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your connection has implicit transactions turned on, all statements must succeed, or they will all be rolled back.  You probably know that's how it works when manipulating data (insert, update etc.) but you may not realize it also happens for table creation and many other DDL commands.

You can avoid this behavior by:

1. Adding an explicit COMMIT after each CREATE TABLE command
2. Turning on AUTOCOMMIT in your session

Many DBMSs only apply transactions to data manipulation, but some like Postgres do not.

Comment: Thank you, the `COMMIT` is the very solution I am seeking. If I recalled the term `COMMIT`, I might have described my question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about transaction?
**successful:**

```
t=# begin;
BEGIN
t=# create table so56(i int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# create table so57 as select * from pg_tables limit 1;
SELECT 1
t=# end;
COMMIT
t=# select * from so56;
 i
---
(0 rows)
```

**not successful**

```
t=# begin;
BEGIN
t=# create table so56(i int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# select * from so56;
 i
---
(0 rows)

t=# create table so57 as select * from not_existing_table_to_raise_error;
ERROR:  relation "not_existing_table_to_raise_error" does not exist
LINE 1: create table so57 as select * from not_existing_table_to_rai...
                                           ^
t=# end;
ROLLBACK
t=# select * from so56;
ERROR:  relation "so56" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from so56;
```

second case first table creation rollback if first table creation fails

Comment: Does the `begin;` starts a transaction? Without it, the table `so56` will not roll back?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, `COMMIT` is the very solution that can solve my concern.